# Detecting a curve shape from a signal

Tags: signal-processing, match, detection, shapes, curve

I am trying to detect a curve of a certain **shape** and its **position** from a signal as shown below:

(link to picture: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ab5j45&s=6)

I would be getting the signal as an array of floats.

Due to noise and other variations, the curve may not be exact so I can not use simple number matching. I was wondering if there is something in OpenCV which I can use for this.

Note that I will need to detect curves of different shapes and their position in the signal but if I know to detect one type, I can use the same method to detect other types.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

I would try to define a parametric mathematical function representing the shape you want to match.

Then all you need to do is to apply a technique (For instance [least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares)) to get the values of the parameters that best matches the curve over your signal.

You may want to match your function against a sliding window, especially if you want to match  multiple events in your signal.

Answer (score 0):

Noise and "other variations" are high frecuencies, so you need to filter the signal with a low-pass filter (for filtering, use the convolution operation). It seems that you signal have very low frecuencies (below 5KHz maybe?). Alfter filtering, look at your signal, and when you get the desired curve shape, apply numerical matching.

Comment: I am not sure if that will work as the actual numbers in the curve will vary from signal to signal  e.g., if I get 1-2-3-4-3-2-3-2 in one case, I might get 1.2-2.1-3.4-4.1-3.5-2.1-3-2.1 which will generate a similar shape but not the same numbers but is still counted as a match.

Answer (score 0):

Matched filter has the highest peak at the integer position in a signal that best matches the given shape (or energy of the pattern to be matched). But in addition to that, often the neighboring values of the matched filter output can be used to fine tune the position by calculating `tau = a-b/(a+b)` (IIRC), where a=peak value and b is the second best value.

This works especially well, if the signal to be matched has good auto correlation characteristics -- one high peak and close to zero at +-1 from the peak (basically means detecting pilot signals).